# How can I write code to purposefully eat up RAM and CPU resources?

Tags: memory, filesystems

I have written code in Ruby and C before that has accomplished similar purposes, but I think my situation is a bit trickier now. As I said, I need to purposefully write code that ties up the resources on a machine, and measure where and when these events happen.

Are there any libraries/modules out there that do this, and if not, what would be the best way to accomplish this? Should I flood the processor with huge numbers and make it try to find primes? Should I shoot tons of packets to one of the machines and wait till it crashes?

I have spent the past 2 days writing code to accomplish various tasks related to this, but I'm dissatisfied because even when I do accomplish my task, I can't get any real data out on where, why, and when these events are happening. ANY suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: might be a better question for stackoverflow

Comment: It's really difficult to read your question and figure out what question(s) you're asking. I also have a vague feeling that you're reinventing wheels.

Comment: That's fair enough @Iain, but could you recommend tools that have already been created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider using the `stress` utility in Linux. I'm assuming this is a Linux system. Either way, "stress" allows you to target the subsystem of your choice and load it accordingly.